# Blazor RadzenDataGrid not showing pretty grid

Tags: c#, blazor

Hoping someone can help me find the issue. Im really new to blazor, so if its a obvious mistake, dont yell at me :D

Im making a basic data grid that pulls data from a database and displays it using RadzenDataGrid.

I've made the grid, but for some reason it just shows a basic table on the page, it doesnt have that nice sorting and filtering options or the usual data grid looks.

The code for the data grid:

```
@page "/assessmentresults"
@using NotificationGUI.Web.Components.Interfaces
@using Radzen.Blazor
@using NotificationGUI.Web.Components.DataModel.Schemas.Calc
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@using System.Linq
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
@using BlazorDownloadFile;

@attribute [StreamRendering]
@inject EMIRAssessmentResultsDbContext dbContext

<PageTitle>Assessment Results</PageTitle>

<h1>Assessment Results</h1>


<RadzenDataGrid TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Data="@notificationData" AllowFiltering="true" PageSize="100" AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnResize ="true">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="AssessmentDateTime" Title="AssessmentDateTime" MinWidth="200px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="RBLKey" Title="RBL " MinWidth="100px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="" Title="Notify NCA" MinWidth= "100px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="EntityResponsibleForReportingLEI" Title="Notify ERR" MinWidth="230px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="NumOfAffReports" Title="NumOfAffReports" MinWidth="150px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="ThresholdConstantX" Title="ThresholdConstantX" MinWidth="170px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="ThersholdConstantY" Title="ThresholdConstantY" MinWidth="170px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="AverageMontlyNum" Title="AverageMontlyNum" MinWidth="170px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="NumOfAffReports_AverageMontlyNum" Title="Calculated percentage" MinWidth="180px" />
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="EMIR_AssementResults" Property="EntityResponsibleForReportingLEI" Title="ERRs" MinWidth="100px" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {

    List<EMIR_AssementResults> notificationData;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Retrieve data for RadzenDataGrid
        notificationData = await dbContext.EMIR_AssessmentResultsData.ToListAsync();
    }

}
```

And when I launch it, it just looks like crap:
[image]

Any suggestions what might be wrong? I thought its supposed to automatically make it pretty with the tables and everything.
Something more like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you included a call in your html file to the Radzen's CSS and JS? https://blazor.radzen.com/get-started

Comment: Have you followed the Radzen installation instructions?   I'm no Radzen expert, but this looks like the css file is missing from `App.razor` - see https://blazor.radzen.com/docs/guides/getting-started/installation.html#include-the-css-and-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are using necessary JS and CSS reference in your `wwwroot/index.html` or `_Host.cshtml`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css">

<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
```

the script tag should be before the closing `</body>`

I noticed that one of your columns has a `Property=""` which is empty. This may potentially cause an issue. Each column needs to be bound to a property of `EMIR_AssementResults`

Please see [readme](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor) Get started with Radzen Blazor Components section

Comment: Yesss, this was the answer.
I assumed that all this stylesheet stuff comes by default when you make a basic blazor app (using the template they give you in visual studio) but I guess I was wrong.

By adding this, it now works.

Thank you!

Comment: also check the styles on their webpage you can than custimize your app for darkmode so easily by just swapping css links

Comment: Will do!
Do you happen to know why the sorting and filtering options might not work? I dont see any specific configurations we must do to get this working besides adding the tags to allow filtering.

The webpage loads, and data is there, but when I click to sort, nothing happens, and when I click filter, it doesnt let me select anything in the pop-up box that shows up.